# Images in local html file not showing up in IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, local

I’ve been developing a static site locally (not localhost, just previewing the local files in the browser) and all works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but the images in the html aren’t showing up in IE. Any versions of IE. Also, the Google Fonts aren’t loading.  The images called in the css DO work though. It takes a really long time to load the page and sometimes it times out.

I’ve uploaded it all to a beta site, and from the server, everything works fine in IE.

I even took the files home and looked at the site on my home version of IE on my own computer, and it shows up fine there, so it looks like it’s something with this computer or version of IE? I'm using IE9.

-- here are the errors in the console. they are all related to @font-face; even when I comment out the link to the Google font, images still do not show up.

```
CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted.
```

C6HYlRF50SGJq1XyXj04z2msoyWrDyoltQVIP7q_RGg.eot
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
C6HYlRF50SGJq1XyXj04zzBIQ40lcwWW3vj9tFMKvqw.eot
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
xgzbb53t8j-Mo-vYa23n5nZ2MAKAc2x4R1uOSeegc5U.eot
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
q9w3H4aeBxj0hZ8Osfi3dzoGYR7Z3iWH66EXnaJoKgg.eot
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
q9w3H4aeBxj0hZ8Osfi3d9P2OS6Bzu7BENq0TH5sayk.eot
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
C6HYlRF50SGJq1XyXj04z3l4twXkwp3_u9ZoePkT564.woff
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
C6HYlRF50SGJq1XyXj04z9Od4RnLmtUrdSQkDmC5b8k.woff
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
q9w3H4aeBxj0hZ8Osfi3dy1dfeF-hbOdKKuBDEXxqhQ.woff
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
xgzbb53t8j-Mo-vYa23n5nhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff
    CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
q9w3H4aeBxj0hZ8Osfi3d3pumDtkw9GHrrDfd7ZnWpU.woff

-- i am using the boilerplate template

the image code:

```
<img src="img/icon-fb.png" alt="facebook" width="32" height="32">
```

the images are in a folder called "img" which is in the site's root. the index.html file is in the site's root.

Comment: Check your IE script console, for errors.

Comment: You need to post your code. Preferably stripped down to a minimal example that still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: As @DaveRager said, you need to post a small code snippet that demonstrates your problem.